# Using Spark to retrieve a HDFS file protected by Kerberos

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kerberos, hadoop-yarn

I am having issues setting up my spark environment to read from a kerberized HDFS file location.

At the moment I have tried to do the following:

```
def ugiDoAs[T](ugi: Option[UserGroupInformation])(code: => T) = ugi match {
case None => code
case Some(u) => u.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction[T] {
  override def run(): T = code
})
}
val sparkConf = defaultSparkConf.setAppName("file-test").setMaster("yarn-client")

val sc = ugiDoAs(ugi) {new SparkContext(conf)} 

val file = sc.textFile("path")
```

It fails at the point of creating the Spark Context, with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:104)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getClusterMetrics(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:155)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
```

Has anyone got a simple example on how to allow spark to connect to a kerberized HDFS location?

I know that spark needs to be in Yarn mode to be able to make it work, but the login method does not seem to be working in this respect. Although I know that the User Group Information (ugi) object is valid as I have used it to connect to ZK in the same object and HBase.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm conf/spark-env.sh is configured or:

`export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf`

This must point to the client configs for your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that the client is trying to talk to HDFS unauthenticated and that's being rejected. make sure the UGI really is secure by logging it, and do some basic hadoop filesystem code before going to spark; that should make it easier to track down